# Get variable value of a function without setting it globally

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to get a variable value inside a function without having to set it globally?

I know this is possible:

```
var testvalue;
function setTestValue(){
   testvalue = 30;
}
```

if you `console.log` this outside the setTestValue function you will get: 30. Which is clear.

But is there also a possibility to have the same effect but without a global variable?

```
function setTestValue(){
   var testvalue = 30;
}
console.log(testvalue); // will print undefined
```

The reason why I want this is because I can not change the Javascript file where this function is created. I can only read it and not write it so I need it a workaround.

PS. It might be that this question is already been aksed on stackoverflow but I could not really find it. So if there is, please provide the links to that question.Thanks!

Comment: No, it's not. That variable is scoped to that function.

Comment: Thanks! Simple and clear answer! @tymeJV

Comment: if you can't change the code, what problem does the presence of this global variable cause that you are trying to solve?

Comment: FWIW, assuming you are trying to do this in browser, you can use dev tools to inspect the value by using breakpoints inside the function. That is as close to "accessing" the variable defined inside the function as you can get.

Comment: @Rotan075 can you show us the function code you want to access a private variable? Usually there is an workaround.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? May be there's a painless (*or one with least pain :-)*) approach.

Comment: @PeterKA I need to check the variable value so that I can check them via an unit test. Therefore I can not really change the function code;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works (if you don't have `var` keyword before the variable in the function )

```js
function foo() {
    bar = 10; // variable without var comes under window scope so you can access them outside fuction
}
foo();// you have to call the function to set its value
alert(bar) // window.bar also gives 10
```

Answer (score 0):

why not returning the var in the function:

```
function setTestValue(){
   var testvalue;
   do whatever to assign value

   return testvalue;
}

console.log(setTestValue());
```